# How to kill all Running jobs and then make Stopped jobs being Running?

Tags: linux, jobs

I've curious about how can I kill all Running jobs at first, and then change all Stopped jobs to Running status in Linux. I have googled a lot but I did not found anything. I just reached a command `kill $(jobs -ps)` that kills all jobs (whether running or stopped).
This is my `jobs` output:

```
[1]  92231 Running                 tail -f myfile &
[2]  92232 Stopped                 tail -f myfile
[3]  92234 Stopped                 tail -f myfile
[4]  92236 Stopped                 tail -f myfile
[5]  92237 Running                 tail -f myfile &
[6]  92238 Stopped                 tail -f myfile
[7]  92239 Running                 tail -f myfile &
[8]  92240 Stopped                 tail -f myfile
[9]  92241 Stopped                 tail -f myfile
[10]  92243 Stopped                 tail -f myfile
[11]  92244 Stopped                 tail -f myfile
[12]  92245 Stopped                 tail -f myfile
[13]  92246 Stopped                 tail -f myfile
[14]  92247 Stopped                 tail -f myfile
[15]  92248 Stopped                 tail -f myfile
[16]  92249 Stopped                 tail -f myfile
[17]  92250 Stopped                 tail -f myfile
[18]  92251 Stopped                 tail -f myfile
[19]  92252 Stopped                 tail -f myfile
[20]  92253 Stopped                 tail -f myfile
[21]  92255 Stopped                 tail -f myfile
[22]  92256 Stopped                 tail -f myfile
[23]  92258 Stopped                 tail -f myfile
[24]  92259 Stopped                 tail -f myfile
[25]  92260 Stopped                 tail -f myfile
[26]  92261 Running                 tail -f myfile &
[27]  92262 Stopped                 tail -f myfile
[28]  92263 Stopped                 tail -f myfile
[29]  92264 Stopped                 tail -f myfile
[30]  92267 Stopped                 tail -f myfile
[31]  92268 Stopped                 tail -f myfile
[32]  92269 Stopped                 tail -f myfile
[33]  92270 Stopped                 tail -f myfile
[34]  92271 Stopped                 tail -f myfile
[35]- 92272 Stopped                 tail -f myfile
[36]+ 92273 Stopped                 tail -f myfile
```

At first, I want to kill all Running processes, and then I want to make the other Stopped ones being Running.

How may I reach this output? I've been thinking about for loop but I'm not sure if I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First some useful `jobs` options from the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Builtins.html#Job-Control-Builtins):

> -p
> List only the process ID of the job’s process group leader.
>
> -r
> Display only running jobs.
>
> -s
> Display only stopped jobs.

So to kill all running jobs we can do:

```
kill $(jobs -p -r)
```

And to restart all stopped jobs:

```
kill -SIGCONT $(jobs -p -s)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @kaylum. I use Ubuntu and there are no entries in man and info for jobs command, so I did find nothing in my terminal.